# Which is correct? "build a new habit" or "make a new habit" or create a new habit?

Tags: single-word-requests

Which sentence is correct? You should build a new habit, or you should make a new habit, or you should create a new habit.

Comment: Depends greatly on context/tone.

Answer (score 5):

Comparing the frequency of use of ***develop the habit*** (which may show intention or not) with *build, make, create* ... **or** *adopt* the new habit shows that the former is by far the most idiomatic. [[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Adopt+the+habit%2Cmake+the+habit%2Ccreate+the+habit%2Cbuild+the+habit%2Cdevelop+the+habit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAdopt%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccreate%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuild%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdevelop%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0)]

This collocational preference is true with the more obviously intentional development encouraged by the string 'you should develop the habit' ( ... form ... / ... adopt ...). [[Google 5grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+should+adopt+the+habit%2Cyou+should+develop+the+habit%2Cyou+should+build+the+habit%2Cyou+should+f&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20should%20develop%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20should%20f%3B%2Cc0)].

Comment: (Is there any difference between "Google **n**grams" and "Google **5**grams"?)

Comment: There is a good reason why *develop* is the most frequently used verb: it conveys that idea that this is a process that takes time.

Comment: An ngram is a graph showing frequency of use found in a given corpus of a string of n orthographic words. 2-grams, 5-grams, 17-grams (not provided by Google) and I suppose 1-grams. etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Habit* has at least two meanings:

> something that you do often and regularly, sometimes without knowing that you are doing it
>
> a special piece of long clothing worn by monks and nuns
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/habit)

One may create or make clothing but not build it. I therefore assume you refer to the first meaning, related to repetitive behaviour.

Google ngram shows all uses, together with my suggested fourth alternative of *adopting* a habit.

> [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Adopt+the+habit%2Cmake+the+habit%2Ccreate+the+habit%2Cbuild+the+habit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAdopt%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccreate%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuild%20the%20habit%3B%2Cc0)

I therefore suggest that all four verbs may be safely used. *Building*, *making* and *creating* put the emphasis on your own part in the new habit; *adopting* puts the emphasis on your copying a behaviour that already exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions above the terms 'form' and 'establish' are sometimes used for the process of training yourself to do something more or less automatically.
For instance [this website](https://www.developgoodhabits.com/long-form-habit/) although it predominently uses 'develop' also uses 'form' in the body of the text and [this one](https://www.verywellmind.com/how-long-does-it-really-take-to-build-a-healthy-habit-2224073)although it predominiently uses 'build' also uses 'establish' in the body.